# Why are my media queries responsive on my monitor, but not responsive on my phone or ipad?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

[solanosprinklers.net](http://solanosprinklers.net)

Please refer to the site. I have different color settings so I can see where the resolution changes when decreasing the window size on my PC. Check it out, it responds. The problem is that the phone and tablet are both not responding. What am I missing?

Here are the media queries in the CSS file

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #new_customer {background: green; margin-left:-20% !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #new_customer {background: black; margin-left:-20% !important; }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #new_customer {background: red; margin-left:8% !important; }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #new_customer {background: blue; margin-left: 21% !important; }
}
```

Comment: Your media queries should generally specify width ranges that have no overlap with each other; your example doesn't comply with this.

Comment: Do you mean the 767px and  the 480px ? Then why does the responsiveness work when testing on my PC Monitor ?